# GetStaticMethodId method signature for public static MyClass myMethod()

Tags: java, android, android-ndk

What is the method signature (for use with GetStaticMethodId) for this method:-

```
public static MyView newMyView() {
    return new MyView(RhodesService.getInstance().getContext(), null);
}
```

Is it `"()Lcom/nativestuff/MyView;"`?  (if the package is com.nativestuff?)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yes `()Lcom/nativestuff/MyView;` is correct. In general:

- `B` = byte
- `C` = char
- `D` = double
- `F` = float
- `I` = int
- `J` = long
- `S` = short
- `V` = void
- `Z` = boolean
- `Lfully-qualified-class` = fully qualified class
- `[type` = array of type
- *(argument types)return type* = method type. If no arguments, use empty argument types: `()`. If return type is `void` (or constructor) use *(argument types)V*.

Comment: Observe that the ; is needed after the class name in all situations. This won't work "(Ljava/lang/String)V" but this will "(Ljava/lang/String;)V".

Answer (score 9):

()Lcom/nativestuff/MyView is correct.

You can also find the signature through

```
javap -s -classpath bin/classes com.nativestuff.MyView
```